# How determine significancy of covariance

Tags: matlab, covariance, significance

I was wondering if there is a way to determine the significancy of a co-variance? So, if have two vectors of returns, and then calculate the co-variance, how do determine if the co-variance is significantly different from zero? Is there somehow a way to determine the standard deviation of the co-variance?

Answer (score 0):

The covariance is either zero or not. There is no uncertainty in theory. In practice you may be worried about rounding errors.

In matlab I think it is fairly safe to say that unless the order of magnitude of your found covariance is at least 10 less than the elements in your vectors, you probably have significant covariance.

Otherwise you may want to check your result more thorougly.

## Example

If your vectors contain values whose absolute values add up to 5000000, and your found covariance is like 0.001, it should definitely be significant.

Comment: Dennis thanks for your response.. However, if you have for example hourly data, the difference between ln(price_tt-price_tt-1), where tt=  for example 1200 hour on day t, and tt-1 will be 1100 on day t, will be very small. E[X] and E[Y] will be small, therefore the difference between between X-E[X] and Y-E[Y] will be small, multiplying these two numbers with each other will give even a smaller number. Therefore I do doubting about the significancy of the co-variance estimate.. In matlab I get:   1.0e-03 *

    0.0029    0.0005
    0.0005    0.2229

Comment: @Dennis Certainly, the covariance is either zero or not. But the _estimated_ covariance does have a significance associated to it. So if the estimated covariance (sample covariance) is small, it is meaningful to ask about the confidence (or probability) that the true covariance is zero

Comment: Thanks @Luis Mendo, do you have an idea how to compute the confidence level or probability level?

Comment: @user3599734 Sorry, I don't. But that question would be very suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, @LuisMendo I have posted the question on your suggestion on stats and my question has been answered. Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but as @Luis Mendo mentioned, covariance has scale issue so that its normalized version, correlation might be better measure to test. And [pearson's correlation coefficient test](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/33) is one method to examine its significance.